# How i implement a query to display data by using 3 tables data which are depend on each other?

Tags: mysql, sql

My Three table are like this

```
Requistion                      Item                            Sub_Category

id  |  Item_id | status    Item_id  | name   | sub_cat         sub_cat |  Sub_name 

1   |  10      |  100           10  | apple  |1                     1  |  Fruits     
2   |  20      |  100           20  | Beans  |2                     2  |  Vegitable
3   |  30      |  100           30  | banana |1                     3  |  Drinks
4   |  40      |  200           40  | Water  |3
```

I want to Display all **Sub_name** With below condition

- Requistion Table status=100
- Result Without Duplicate names

As per the above tables Result must be like

```
Sub_name

Fruits
Vegitable
```

Comment: Google any good MySQL tutorial, and look for `INNER JOIN` and `DISTINCT`. Try after reading up on them, and post your attempted query here.

Comment: I searched and i couldn't get it correctly. now i got the point. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `DISTINCT Sub_name` with `JOIN`s this can be done:

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.Sub_name 
           FROM Requistion R
           JOIN Item I 
             ON I.Item_id = R.Item_id
           JOIN Sub_Category S 
             ON S.sub_cat = I.sub_cat
          WHERE R.status = 100
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Requistion INNER JOIN Item on Item.Item_id=Requistion.Item_id INNER JOIN Sub_Category on Sub_Category.sub_cat=Item.sub_cat where STATUS=100
```

Comment: Get Unique name from Duplicated values, can use **DISTINCT** or **GROUP BY** . Thanks for your Support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query to get this using group by to get unique sub_name,

```
select Sub_name from Sub_Category sc
JOIN Item i on i.sub_cat = sc.sub_cat
JOIN Requistion r on r.Item_id = i.Item_id
WHERE r.status = 100
GROUP BY sc.Sub_name
```

You can use distinct for the same,

```
select DISTINCT Sub_name from Sub_Category sc
JOIN Item i on i.sub_cat = sc.sub_cat
JOIN Requistion r on r.Item_id = i.Item_id
WHERE r.status = 100
```

Comment: @LahiruMendis There is no meaningful sense in which the above answer is 'working'. Likewise with any answer here that uses a GROUP BY clause with no aggregating functions.

Comment: @Strawberry I made changes please check now

Comment: Thanks  both of you for giving a clear idea about Distinct and GROUP By. I Got The Point Very Well. @Strawberry

Comment: Unfortunately, the original, incorrect answer remains